# Tab pages being rendered within drawer rather than on main page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, frontend, material-ui

When clicking on a tab, the elements of the page in question are rendered within the drawer for all the positions except for `Appbar` which is rendered on top. How do I render it within the main page whereas the main page= 100% window size - (drawer+AppBar).

The element on all 4 pages are just one-word texts like yon the Home page shown below the main code for reference,

main code:

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import Hidden from '@material-ui/core/Hidden';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import SearchBar from '../TopBar/SearchBar'
import Home from '../Screens/Home'
import home from '../home.svg';
import Contact from '../Screens/Contact'
import contact from '../contact.svg';
import Profile from '../Screens/Profile'
import profile from '../profile.svg';
import Settings from '../Screens/Settings'
import settings from '../settings.svg'
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import { Switch, Route, Link, BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";



const VerticalTabs = withStyles(theme => ({
  flexContainer: {
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  indicator: {
    display: "none"

  },
  root:{
    position:"relative",
    left:-70,
    top:-40,

  },

}))(Tabs);

const MyTab = withStyles(theme => ({
  selected: {
    color: "white",
    borderRight: "none",


  },
  root: {
  //minWidth: 121,
  margin:0,
 paddingBottom:119

  },
  '@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 1205px)':{

    root: {
      minWidth: 100,
    }
  }
}))(Tab);

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,

  },
  tabRoot: {
    minWidth: 10,
  },
});

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',

  },
  menuButton:{
    visibility: "hidden"
  },

  appBar: {
    marginLeft: 300,


  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: 100,
background: "#262A2C",
fontSize:65,
height: 2300,
top:-10


      },


      content: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        padding: theme.spacing(3),

      },

      '@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 1205px)':{
        drawerPaper: {
          width: 80,
      //background: "black"
        },


      },

      '@media (max-width: 600px)':{

        drawerPaper: {
          width: 300,
      //background: "black"
        },
  appBar: {



  },
  menuButton:{
   visibility: "visible"
 },
  }

}));



function ResponsiveDrawer() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);

  function handleChange(event, Value) {
    setValue(Value);
  }



  function handleDrawerToggle() {
    setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
  }

  const drawer = (


         <BrowserRouter>

    <Route
          path="/"
          render={({ location }) => (
            <Fragment>
              <nav>
                  <div className= "tabs" style={{ left: 70, position: "relative", marginTop: 40 ,}}>
      <VerticalTabs value={location.pathname} variant="fullWidth" onChange={handleChange}  
          >
        <MyTab  
        component={Link} to="../Screens/Home"
        icon ={<img 
        className= "home"
        src={home} 
        alt="home" 
        /*Pay FlatIcon or replace by design *//>}
        label={<p className="home-Text" >
        Home
        </p>} 
        />
        <MyTab  
        component={Link} to="../Screens/Contact"
        icon ={<img 
        className= "contact"
        src={contact}  
        alt="contact" 
        /*Pay FlatIcon or replace by design *//>}
        label={<p className="contacts-Text" >
       Contact
        </p>} 
        />
        <MyTab 
             component={Link} to="../Screens/Profile"
        icon={<img 
        className= "profile" 
        src={profile} 
        alt="profile" 
        /*Pay FlatIcon or replace by design *//>}
        label={<p className= "profile-Text" >
       Profile
        </p>} 
        />
        <MyTab 
             component={Link} to="../Screens/Settings"
        icon = {<img
        className= "settings" 
        src={settings} 
         alt="settings"
        /*Pay FlatIcon or replace by design *//>}
        label={<p className="hsettings-Text" >
      Settings
        </p>} 
        />


      </VerticalTabs>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="../Screens/Home" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="../Screeens/Contact"  component={Contact}/>
                <Route path="../Screeens/Profile"  component={Profile}/>
                <Route path="../Screeens/Settings"  component={Settings}/>

              </Switch>
                  </div>
                  </nav>
            </Fragment>
          )}
          />

    </BrowserRouter>



  );

  return (
    <div className="aBar">
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar style={{position:"fixed"}} position="relative" style={{ background: 'transparent', boxShadow: 'none', color: "red"}}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="Open drawer"
            edge="start"
            onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
            className={classes.menuButton}
          >
            <MenuIcon />

          </IconButton>
          <SearchBar />
          <div className="logo">
          <Typography className= "logo-Spec" style={{fontSize:30}}>
          Logo 
          </Typography>
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <nav className={classes.drawer}>
        {/* The implementation can be swapped with js to avoid SEO duplication of links. */}
        <Hidden smUp implementation="css">
          <Drawer
          style={{color:"black"}}
            variant="temporary"
            open={mobileOpen}
            onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
            ModalProps={{
              keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
            }}
          >
            {drawer}
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
        <Hidden xsDown implementation="css">
          <Drawer
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
            variant="permanent"
            open
          >
            {drawer}
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>

      </nav>

    </div>
  );
}




export default  withStyles(styles)(ResponsiveDrawer);
```

Home.js (same for all four pages link through tabs):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';



export default class Home extends Component {
render(){
return (
<div>
 <p style={{fontSize:60,position:"relative", left: 0,top:0}}>Home</p>
</div>
);

}
}
```

App.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import FullMenu from "./Menu/FullMenu"


export default class App extends Component {
render(){
return (
  <html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

</head>
<div>
<FullMenu/>
</div>
</html>
);

}
}
```

Comment: You've entered the `drawer` component in the `<Drawer>` tag, so it will be rendered inside the drawer. Put it outside the `<Drawer>` tag.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work still, it's not there and I tried repositioning it in divs testing it with and without components as parents but they aren't visible. Is it possible to create a demo? Maybe I am simply missing something

Comment: I found the solution, it's fine keeping the drawer, what needed change is to integrate the BrowseRouter in the return with the Switch